# how to downgrade GDAL to version 2.4?

Tags: python, django, installation, geospatial, gdal

I'm trying to push my django app on heroku and i keep getting this message error.

```
 An error occurred while installing gdal==3.1.2! Will try again.
remote:        Installing initially–failed dependencies…
remote:        Collecting gdal==3.1.2
```

... and

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-oj843jp_/gdal/setup.py", line 257, in get_gdal_config
remote:                return fetch_config(option)
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-oj843jp_/gdal/setup.py", line 154, in fetch_config
remote:                raise gdal_config_error(e)
remote:            gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'
remote:
remote:            Could not find gdal-config. Make sure you have installed the GDAL native library and development headers.
```

I think this is happening because i updated the GDAL because of a previous error message and seems that django only support the version 2.4.

i download the 2.4.3 version files and i can't find the command to install it.
i tried pip install gdal==2.4.3  still not working.

I can't get the proper steps to get the right version. Can anyone point me into the right direction?
I'm using a mac catalina

Comment: specifying the version with pip like you did is the right way to do. What error did you get ? It is also possible to install the file that you downloaded locally using `pip -e`

Comment: i got some red message all over the terminal. scary!! .

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal
  Running setup.py clean for gdal
Failed to build gdal
Installing collected packages: gdal
  Attempting uninstall: gdal
    Found existing installation: GDAL 3.1.2
    Uninstalling GDAL-3.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled GDAL-3.1.2
    Running setup.py install for gdal ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: The interesting part unfortunately is right where you stopped pasting, after "out with exit status 1:". Nm, it's `No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'`. So you don't have `libgdal-dev` installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the pip repo for this package is broken and not installing the package correctly. I would advise looking at [this page](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html) for installation through your distribution's package manager. Alternatively, you can install the local file as indicated [here](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/)